# String value of 1 day in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime, time

I need string value of 1 day

"23:59:59" is working but cause delays

"24:00:00" is not working : Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

"1.00:00:00" is not working : Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

here is my code:

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1] 

    @Start datetime, 
    @Finish datetime,
    @TimeRange datetime
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @TimeRanges as TABLE (SessionStart datetime, SessionEnd datetime);

     with TimeRanges as (
  select @Start as StartTime, @Start + @TimeRange as EndTime
  union all
  select StartTime + @TimeRange, EndTime + @TimeRange
    from TimeRanges
    where EndTime < @Finish )
  select StartTime, EndTime, Count( Test.ScenarioID ) as TotalPeaks
    from TimeRanges as TR left outer join
      dbo.Test as Test on TR.StartTime <= Test.SessionStartTime and Test.SessionCloseTime < TR.EndTime
    group by TR.StartTime, TR.EndTime   
END
```

Comment: Why don't you use DATEADD to add the timerange?

Comment: I split the time ranges into specific time for example when @TimeRange = 00:05:00.000 then the code split them into 5 minutes and it works fine but when I want a daily report I need to use "24:00:00.000" or something like "1.00:00:00.000" which means 1 day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying use the `datetime` type as a timespan type which won't work for you.

I suggest you change your timerange parameter to an integer. Then specify that's it's either seconds, minutes, hours, days or whatever.

If you decide to make it days:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1] 

    @Start datetime, 
    @Finish datetime,
    @TimeRange int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @TimeRanges as TABLE (SessionStart datetime, SessionEnd datetime);

     with TimeRanges as (
  select @Start as StartTime, DATEADD(day, @TimeRange, @Start) as EndTime
  union all
  select DATEADD(day, @TimeRange, StartTime), DATEADD(day, @TimeRange, EndTime)
    from TimeRanges
    where EndTime < @Finish )
  select StartTime, EndTime, Count( Test.ScenarioID ) as TotalPeaks
    from TimeRanges as TR left outer join
      dbo.Test as Test on TR.StartTime <= Test.SessionStartTime and Test.SessionCloseTime < TR.EndTime
    group by TR.StartTime, TR.EndTime   
END
```